# detect concentration of date (list in python)

Tags: python

I have a list in Python called `array_my_date` and I need to detect the concentrations of dates.

The criteria are:

- A concentration is defined as more than 3 upcoming dates.
- Dates are considered to be close if they are in a time period of 25 days

```py
array_my_date = []
array_my_date.append(pd.to_datetime('2013-06-24 00:00:00'))
array_my_date.append(pd.to_datetime('2013-06-26 00:00:00'))
array_my_date.append(pd.to_datetime('2013-06-27 00:00:00'))
array_my_date.append(pd.to_datetime('2013-06-29 00:00:00'))
array_my_date.append(pd.to_datetime('2013-07-01 00:00:00'))
array_my_date.append(pd.to_datetime('2013-07-03 00:00:00'))
array_my_date.append(pd.to_datetime('2013-07-04 00:00:00'))
array_my_date.append(pd.to_datetime('2013-07-06 00:00:00'))
array_my_date.append(pd.to_datetime('2013-07-07 00:00:00'))
array_my_date.append(pd.to_datetime('2013-07-08 00:00:00'))

array_my_date.append(pd.to_datetime('2015-03-01 00:00:00'))
array_my_date.append(pd.to_datetime('2015-03-04 00:00:00'))

array_my_date.append(pd.to_datetime('2017-09-29 00:00:00'))
array_my_date.append(pd.to_datetime('2017-10-02 00:00:00'))
array_my_date.append(pd.to_datetime('2017-10-06 00:00:00'))
array_my_date.append(pd.to_datetime('2017-10-07 00:00:00'))
array_my_date.append(pd.to_datetime('2017-10-08 00:00:00'))
array_my_date.append(pd.to_datetime('2017-10-09 00:00:00'))

array_my_date.append(pd.to_datetime('2018-12-09 00:00:00'))
```

The expected output is the first date that had concentration. That is:

```
[Timestamp('2013-06-24 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-09-29 00:00:00')]
```

Comment: Hi @Jane. A good question should include your attempt to solve the problem you have. Please take a look at [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure the list of dates is sorted:

```
dates = sorted(array_my_date)
```

Then, gradually build up a list of concentrations:

```
concentrations = [[dates[0]]]                        # initialize our memory with the first date
for date in dates[1:]:                               # iterate through the rest of the dates
    last_date = concentrations[-1][-1]               # look at the last date we added
    if (date - last_date) <= pd.Timedelta(days=25):  # is it close enough to be in the same group?
        concentrations[-1].append(date)              # if so, then put it in the same group
    else:                                            # otherwise,
        concentrations.append([date])                # make a new group with it at the head
```

This yields the following:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(concentrations)
[[Timestamp('2013-06-24 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2013-06-26 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2013-06-27 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2013-06-29 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2013-07-01 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2013-07-03 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2013-07-04 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2013-07-06 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2013-07-07 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2013-07-08 00:00:00')],
 [Timestamp('2015-03-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2015-03-04 00:00:00')],
 [Timestamp('2017-09-29 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-10-02 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-10-06 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-10-07 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-10-08 00:00:00'),
  Timestamp('2017-10-09 00:00:00')],
 [Timestamp('2018-12-09 00:00:00')]]
```

You can then take the earliest date in each time period by doing something like

```
earliest_of_each = [group[0] for group in concentrations]
```

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can filter to show only the dates:
# [Timestamp ('2013-06-24 00:00:00'), Timestamp ('2017-09-29 00:00:00')]

NOTE: These dates are considered to be concentrations because multiple dates appear close to them.

Comment: The your output earliest_of_each is:

[Timestamp('2013-06-24 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2015-03-01 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2017-09-29 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2018-12-09 00:00:00')]

I need of: 

[Timestamp('2013-06-24 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2017-09-29 00:00:00')]

Comment: You can continue to filter this output however you need to. I'm not sure what's special about those two concentrations in particular, besides that they're odd-numbered and that they're large. You could handle those by adding additional conditions to the `earliest_of_each` list comprehension, e.g. `if len(group) >= 3`.